# Java - regular expression to check if begins and ends with certain characters

Tags: java, string

Considering a string in following format,

> [ABCD:defg] [MSG:information] [MSG2:hello]

How to write regex to check if the line has '[MSG:' followed by some message & ']' and extract text 'information' from above string?

Comment: You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jiov1m/1), `\[MSG:(.*?)\]` and extract the value of group(1). [Java demo](https://ideone.com/n7OJ0O). I suggest you learn some basics of regex.

Comment: Not my downvote. I suggest you [start here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions). It's fun to learn the basics of regex.

Comment: Thank you  @ArvindKumarAvinash . This is what i was looking for. I will learn basics. Many thanks. I am unable to accept it as answer.

Comment: You are most welcome,  Nagaraja. I have converted my comment into an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jiov1m/1), `\[MSG:(.*?)\]` and extract the value of group(1).

**Demo**:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "[ABCD:defg] [MSG:information] [MSG2:hello]";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[MSG:(.*?)\\]").matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find())
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
information
```

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement would be something like

/\[MSG:.+\]/ in standard regex notation. But I would suggest to you that you could use String.indexOf to extract your information

```
String str = ...
int idx = str.indexOf("MSG:");
int idx2 = str.indexOf("]", idx);
val = str.substring(idx + "MSG:".length(), idx2);
```

Comment: I have done this already using indexOf. There are more similar patterns i need to consider. So thought of using regex. many thanks for your suggestion.